# Cancel alert in UserDialogs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to make a simple alert with two options , using UserDialogs package.

I can't figure out how to add a cancel option in UserDialogs...

```
var check =  await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("title", "message", "ok","????");
if (check)
  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Page1");
else 
  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Page2");
```

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/128817/adding-buttons-to-acr-userdialogs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @AndroDevil commented, You can use this code to have *Cancel* and *Ok* button on Alert

```
btnNewPage.Clicked +=async delegate
{
   string action = await DisplayActionSheet("title", "Cancel", "Ok");
   if (action == "Ok")
   {
       //Ok
   }
   else if (action == "Cancel")
   {
       //Cancel
   }
};
```

**Update:** 
 As per your comment if you need it using `UserDialog`

```
var check = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync("message", "title" , "Ok","Cancel");
if (check)
  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Page1");
else 
  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Page2");
```

Comment: I know about that, im only asking if we can do it via UserDialog

Comment: ty, thats the exact thing a wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DisplayAlert` instead, in `Xaml.cs` file.

```
var response = await DisplayAlert("Title", "Message", "Ok", "Cancel");
if (response == true) {
   //Yes action
} else {
   //No action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this:
In App.xaml.cs class

```
public static IUserDialogs UserDialogs => Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance;
```

And whenever you need just use like this:
Do not trust the string.
Check the OK, if it is false, user has declined.

```
App.UserDialogs.Prompt(new PromptConfig
        {
            CancelText = "Cancel",
            OkText = "Add",
            InputType = InputType.Url,
            Placeholder = "Custom URL",
            Title = "Enter custom url",
            IsCancellable = true,
            OnAction = async (result) =>
            {
                //user declined
                if (result.Ok is false) return;

                //User pressed ok button
            },
        });
```